# How to fill data column with factor levels

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume i have a dataframe with a number of rows :

```
nrows=4961
x=1:nrows
```

and a vector of levels :

```
y=iris$Species
```

I'm searching the following output :

```
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
   [9] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"    
  [17] "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
  [25] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
  [33] "virginica"  "setosa" ...(etc until reaching the length nrows=4961 )
```

Comment: I had found a solution : rep(levels(iris$Species),nrow(melted))[1:nrow(melted)]

Comment: May someone give a better suggestion

Comment: Does `data.frame(x, y)` not produce the desired output?

Comment: Or `data = data.frame(x); data$y = y`?

Comment: Error in data.frame(x, y) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4961, 150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length.out` argument in `rep` -

```
nrows = 4961
y = iris$Species
z <- rep(y, length.out = nrows)
```

Comment: Yes , me also i found :  rep(levels(iris$Species),nrow(melted))[1:nrow(melted)]